# MVC Configuration Seed method not inserting Primary Key specified

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with MVC 4 doing a side project. In my Configuration.cs I have my Seed method coded out and it works fine except for one thing. The table is completely empty with no records in it. I specify that I want the PK ID to start at 100001 for tracking purposes. I update the database and the record is created but the PK value for ID is just 1. If I make changes and update it again then the ID is 2. It is not taking my specified PK value and I cannot figure out why. I should be able to specify any PK value I want as long as it falls within the data constraints and is unique. Is this not able to be done or am I missing something? Can you define what value you want the ID to start and then increment from there? Any help is appreciated.

```
protected override void Seed(Helpdesk_Escalation_Tool.Models.OutageDb context)
    {

        context.Outages.AddOrUpdate(
            new Outage
            {
                Id = 100001,
                Site = "SL, DG",
                Project = "ATT UVB, ATT RST",
                Subject = "Agents cannot process orders in CRM",
                StartTime = DateTime.Now,
                EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
                AgentCount = 200,
                Resolved = true,
                Resolution = "Client resolved issue",
                Ticket = "123456789",
                Downtime = 120
            });    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a no identity primary key column,you can set the id manually,you  need to  add

```
[Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]  this  attribute on the top of id property
```

Decorate your id properties with the following Attributes (DatabaseGenerated...).

> ```
> public class Sites
> {
>     [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
>     public int SiteID { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public string Tags { get; set; }
>     public string Description { get; set; }
>     public string URI { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Comment: I am familiar with some of the Data Annotations but not all. Thank you, I appreciate the help!